# onchange without click on another location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used onchange on an input element, but the event handler function won't run until the field loses focus.

I want the function in onchange to run in real time. Onkeyup doesn't seem to be a solution, because it will trigger the function when any key is pressed, even if it doesn't change the field contents (for example, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>).

What should I do?

Comment: change of what? Where's your current code?

Comment: @rajat: onkeyup not interest.for examle I have field that onchange request data from server.onkeyup when user press ctrl or alt or up/down keys data will sent to server while data no change

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event onpropertychange (IE) or DOMAttrModified (FF, Opera).
Or there is also oninput event supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: thanks.but in IE when I press Backspace or Delete keys function not run.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Buggy behavior of onpropertychange and oninput is described in my first link. In this case you should use onkeypress event.